# DocuSign c# .NET core examples

Tags: c#, templates, .net-core, docusignapi, signing

I am looking for some C# code examples (creating an API), to open a template, sign in and give back status. I do see examples of "Embedded Signing Ceremony' but that for the document, in the project. 
I need to open up an already existing template and signer should sign in and my application to get back the signed status.

please advice.

thank u.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question likely needs to be a lot more specific. As it stands it is likely to be closed as off-topic (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because it is too generic and opinion-based. Here is another link on asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: --https://gist.github.com/AnishTiwari/2b15448e8650e7a2510ef48c81624216 -- Maybe this could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can used [EG03 Example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/blob/master/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/Controllers/Eg009UseTemplateController.cs) to send an envelope using DS Server TemplateId. [Git Examples](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core) has many other samples as well using C sharp. To get back the application status for an envelope, it is recommended to use [DS Connect](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect).